# Alphabetize columns/rows in a distance matrix in R

Tags: r, distance

This should be relatively simple but for some reason, I'm coming up stumped.

I want to reorder a phylogenetic distance matrix so that the columns are in alphabetical order.

Here is a quick example:

```
require("ape")
set.seed(5)
dist(cophenetic(rtree(5)))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `T <- dist(cophenetic(rtree(5)))`

T is of class `dist` so it doesnt have names, just labels.
You can order its labels

```
ordering <- sort(attr(T, "Labels"))
```

You can coerce it into a matrix, and then sort it

```
T.mat <- as.matrix(T)[ordering, ordering]
```

Then as @Roland suggested, convert it back to `dist`

```
T  <- as.dist(T.mat)
```

If you would like to control the format of the matrix, you can use the following

```
T.fm <- format(T.mat, digits=3, nsmall=3)
T.fm[row(T.fm) < col(T.fm)] <- ""
print(T.fm, quote=F)

#      t1    t2    t3    t4    t5   
# t1 0.000                        
# t2 3.436 0.000                  
# t3 1.309 3.632 0.000            
# t4 2.145 2.338 2.530 0.000      
# t5 1.756 2.783 2.173 1.136 0.000

T  <- as.dist(T.fm)
T
#       t1    t2    t3    t4
# t2 3.436                  
# t3 1.309 3.632            
# t4 2.145 2.338 2.530      
# t5 1.756 2.783 2.173 1.136
```

Comment: Nice, I used `as.dist` to bring it back to a class "dist"

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
require("ape")
set.seed(5)
res <- dist(cophenetic(rtree(5)))
res <- as.matrix(res)
res <- as.dist(res[order(rownames(res)),order(colnames(res))])
```